# Android Lollipop Button Ripple not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-5.0-lollipop

When a regular button is defined in the XML layout code (android L) it has a ripple effect by default on press which is working fine. However, when a regular button is defined and a specific background color is added to the button, the ripple effect is removed. How would I go about adding the button ripple to the button again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set button background property to your own *RippleDrawable*. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Touch).

Comment: What if the link is dead?

Comment: Thanks for the link and I prefer implemented in `android:foreground` so the ripple wont get overlapped by layout above it.